# unable to match string 'g++' at the beginning of the line

Tags: regex, perl

working through a system.log file and i am trying to extract lines where 'g++' is at the beginning of the line.

Here is the Perl one liner regular expression that i have tried to write

```bash
perl -l -n -e 'print if m/(g\+{2})/;' system.log
```

When I place `^` at `/^(g\+{2})/` it seems to negate the match instead of operating at the beginning of the line.

Any pointers?

I expect the `^` to match the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

`/^(g\+{2})/` is correct.

```
$ printf 'f++ no\ng++ yes\nno g++\n' | perl -l -n -e 'print if m/^(g\+{2})/;'
g++ yes
```

(The parens and `-l` are unnecessary. It could be written `perl -ne'print if /^g\+\+/'`.)

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. There is a single space before each line in the log file and thus the regex wasn't matching. Adapting it to ignore white space at the beginning the line, `perl -l -n -e 's/^\s+//; print if m/\b^(g\+{2})/;' system.log` worked for me.

Comment: That `\b` makes no sense.

Comment: `perl -l -n -e 's/^\s+//; print if m/^(g\+{2})/;' system.log`